# Prefix for section headings, but not in captions

Tags: sectioning

A journal, which I intend to submit to, asks that section headings are preceded with `<heading number ...>`. So I used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68487/67042) to create my custom prefix to the section headings:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\textless heading level 1\textgreater \ \arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\textless heading level 2\textgreater \ \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\textless heading level 3\textgreater \ \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

This works very well for the headers, but when I `\cite{ch:foo}` the reference appears as "*<heading level 2> 2.3*", which I would like to avoid. The [second answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68551/67042) on the question gives an alternative solution, which seems to me (as a Latex rookie) more of a hack:

```
\makeatletter
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@ }%
  {-3.5ex\@plus -1ex\@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\noindent\normalfont \Large \bfseries Prefix\ }%
}
\makeatother
```

Can you propose a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\@seccntformat}{heading level #2 \@seccntformat}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Foo}
\subsection{Foo}
\subsubsection{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Not sure what this does, but it works!

Comment: @n1000 `\(sub...)section` use internal `\@startsection` which use internal `\@sect` which use internal `\@seccntformat` that format the number of `(sub...)section` here we redefine `\@sect`  by adding the prefix just before `\@seccntformat` using`\patchcmd` for shortness.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but do you have any clue why this will not work when I `\usepackage{hyperref}`?

Comment: this is because `hyperref` redefine some internals command to do the job. In this case just load `hyperref` after you make the change.